# Loop through .each(function) properly and format number string to phone number

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to loop through my results and format each number string. The first result is formated correctly, but not the second result or any result after the first.

```
 $('#phoneResults').each(function(){              
     //Only the first result is being altered! Ugh.
     var string = $(this).html();
     $(this).html(string.substring(0,3) + '.' + string.substring(3,6) + '.' + string.substring(6,10))     
 });
```

Comment: Please expand.  What is the content of #phoneResults?  (That element does not exist on your site)....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Likely because the `#` refers to an element ID, which by convention is unique.  jQuery will treat this as a single item, so iteration will yield only a single result.

Maybe try something like:

```
$('.phoneResults').each(function() { 
    // your code here 
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I know better. I gave my element a class name and then applied it. Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a duplicated id `#phoneresults`.  Id's must e unique.  When your selector operates, it is finding the first element with the ID and then stopping as there should not be any other elements with the ID.  So your `each()` function is not operating on multiple elements.

Make this a class and change your selector to `.phoneresults` and you should be good to go.